# The type name 'does not exist' when I try to add it in the @model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

My controller:

```
public class ManufacturersController : Controller
{

    public Manufacturer_vm man1 { get; set; }

    public ManufacturersController() 
    {

        this.man1 = new Manufacturer_vm();

    }


    //
    // GET: /Manufacturerers/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        if (Session["manufacturer"] != null)
        {

            man1 = (Manufacturer_vm)Session["manufacturer"];

        }

        return View(man1);
    }
}
```

And in my view:

```
@model Example.Controllers.ManufacturersController.Manufacturer_vm

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
```

But it is saying "The type name 'Manufacturer_vm' does not exist in the type 'Example.Controllers.ManufacturersController

I have another class of Manufacturer_vm where I get the variable man1 but I am unable to use my index view without being able to add the @model

Here is my Manufacturer_vm class

```
public class Manufacturer_vm
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Country { get; set; }

    public int YearStarted { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Vehicle_vm> Vechicles { get; set; }


    public Manufacturer_vm()
    {

        this.Id = 0;
        this.Name = "Car";
        this.Country = "Canada";
        this.YearStarted = 0;
        this.Vechicles = new List<Vehicle_vm>();

    }

    public class Manufacturer
    {

        public ICollection<Manufacturer_vm> Manufacturer { get; set; }

        public Manufacturer()
        {

            this.Manufacturer = new List<Manufacturer_vm>();

        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Where is Manufacturer_vm  class defined ??

Comment: @Selman22 it's in the controllers folder? im pretty new to asp.net. it's its own class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you didn't define your `Manufacturer_vm` in your `ManufacturersController.` You have just a property of type `Manufacturer_vm` in your Controller. When you setting your model, you should specify where is your class defined.Probably you define it into your Models,look at what is the `namespace` of your `Manufacturer_vm class,` if it's in the `Controller` folder you should use this:

```
@model Example.Controllers.Manufacturer_vm
```

Comment: Hmm..so far it seems as if just adding the Manufacturer_vm by itself is working but i have to try some things with it to see if it works

Comment: Yes it could work.Actually if you write `@model Manufacturer_vm` Visual studio should suggest you full path.If the namespace of this class is added the web config file under the Views folder,then you can use your class with it's name.No need for specify the namespace